# Сокращенная запись условия Python

Tags: python

Видел где-то сокращенную запись, но точно не могу вспомнить.

```py
a = 6
a += 1 if a % 3 ==0
```

Что-то такое. Как правильно написать?

Comment: или a += 1 a%3==0

Comment: вот такое ? `a += 1 if a % 3 ==0 else 0`

Comment: Спасибо, ахах!!!!) Заработало. Если есть вариант еще удобнее буду рад!)

Comment: Т.к. `True` численно равно `1`, то можно просто `a += a % 3 == 0`

Comment: Спасибо! Супер, это так логично )

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = first if condition else second
```